# Self Referencing или Self-Join отношение как правильно сделать запрос?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Вот такая таблица

```sql
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Employees] (
[Id]        INT           IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
[Name]      NVARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
[ManagerId] INT           NULL,
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC),
CONSTRAINT [FK_Employees_Employees] FOREIGN KEY ([ManagerId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Employees] ([Id])
);
```

Такой запрос

```sql
SELECT Id, Name, ManagerId
FROM dbo.Employees;
```

дает такой результат

```
+----+----------+-----------+
| Id |   Name   | ManagerId |
+----+----------+-----------+
|  1 | Иван     | NULL      |
|  2 | Мария    | 7         |
|  3 | Кристина | 7         |
|  4 | Виктор   | 1         |
|  5 | Сергей   | 1         |
|  6 | Григорий | 7         |
|  7 | Мирон    | 1         |
+----+----------+-----------+
```

Если сделать такой запрос

```sql
SELECT em.Id
     , em.Name  AS 'Manager'
     , m.Name
FROM dbo.Employees AS em
RIGHT JOIN dbo.Employees AS m
    ON em.Id = m.ManagerId
ORDER BY em.Id;
```

получаем так

```
+------+---------+----------+
|  Id  | Manager |   Name   |
+------+---------+----------+
| NULL | NULL    | Иван     |
| 1    | Иван    | Виктор   |
| 1    | Иван    | Сергей   |
| 1    | Иван    | Мирон    |
| 7    | Мирон   | Григорий |
| 7    | Мирон   | Мария    |
| 7    | Мирон   | Кристина |
+------+---------+----------+
```

Так вот пытаюсь перевернуть и сделать `LEFT JOIN`

```sql
SELECT em.Id
     , em.Name  
     , m.Name AS 'Manager'
FROM dbo.Employees AS em
LEFT JOIN dbo.Employees AS m
    ON em.Id = m.ManagerId
ORDER BY m.Id;
```

и получаю такое

```
+----+----------+----------+
| Id |   Name   | Manager  |
+----+----------+----------+
|  2 | Мария    | NULL     |
|  3 | Кристина | NULL     |
|  4 | Виктор   | NULL     |
|  5 | Сергей   | NULL     |
|  6 | Григорий | NULL     |
|  7 | Мирон    | Мария    |
|  7 | Мирон    | Кристина |
|  1 | Иван     | Виктор   |
|  1 | Иван     | Сергей   |
|  7 | Мирон    | Григорий |
|  1 | Иван     | Мирон    |
+----+----------+----------+
```

Как исправить и получить слева полный список сотрудников, а справа кто у них менеджер?

Comment: А если у них нет менеджера? Их выводить или нет?

Comment: @YuryBakharev да нужно вывести.

Comment: Почему бы вам в первом варианте не изменить порядок вывода столбцов в предложении SELECT?

Comment: @SergeyMoiseenko да, спасибо, помогло. Чёт я сам не догадался. Хотя интересно как все же сделать с left join, тоже.

Comment: @Bulson можем мы продолжить говорить в чат комнате? https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/106616/yuraplusev

Comment: @YuryBakharev я так и не понял где в этом чате можно хоть что-то написать в ответ, так что сорян, общение не получилось.

Comment: @Bulson Там просто я должен был кнопку нажать и у вас , должно появиться, попробуйте еще раз зайти!

Comment: @Bulson мы могли бы поговорить, лично? По любому каналу связи.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Если нужно получить только список сотрудников с менеджерами, а тех у кого нет менеджера не выводить, то вам нужно сделать вот такой запрос

```
SELECT em.Id
     , em.Name  
     , m.Name AS 'Manager'
FROM dbo.Employees AS em
JOIN dbo.Employees AS m
    ON em.Id = m.ManagerId
ORDER BY m.Id;
```

Если нужно получить весь список сотрудников и даже тех у кого нет менеджера, то ваш запрос с LEFT JOIN это сделает.

Если нужно получить всех менеджеров, даже тех у кого нет сотрудников (альтернатива правому соединению из вашего запроса с правым соединением), то запрос будет выглядеть так:

```
SELECT em.Id , em.Name , m.Name AS 'Manager' 
   FROM dbo.Employees AS m 
LEFT JOIN dbo.Employees AS em ON em.Id = m.ManagerId 
ORDER BY m.Id
```

Comment: Понятно, спасибо. Только мой запрос с left join работает не так как хотелось бы.

Comment: а что конкретно в нем не так?

Comment: При левом соединении вы получили всех сотрудников, даже тех у кого нет менеджера. При правом вы получили всех менеджером, даже тех у кого нет сотрудника. При обычном (join) соединении получили сотрудников с менеджерами

Comment: При левом соединении, как можно видеть по результатам, получается неожиданное, для меня по крайней мере, дублирование отдельных записей, хотя при правом соединении такого эффекта нет. Вот я и не могу понять, как же сделать зеркальное отражение `right join`. Можете подсказать?

Comment: У вас получается, что, например у Мирона, два менеджера. И вам нужно для одного клиента вывести список его менеджеров через запятую?

Comment: В вашем запросе на правое соединение m.Name является менеджером, em.Name сотрудником. Сейчас вы считаете, исходя из запроса, что em.Name as Manager. Но это не так. Правый запрос вам вернул результат, как если бы вы написали запрос с левым соединением вот так SELECT em.Id
     , em.Name  
     , m.Name AS 'Manager'
FROM dbo.Employees AS m
 LEFT JOIN dbo.Employees AS em ON em.Id = m.ManagerId
ORDER BY m.Id;

Comment: Мне нужно сделать `left join` противоположный правому соединению.

Comment: SELECT em.Id , em.Name , m.Name AS 'Manager' FROM dbo.Employees AS m LEFT JOIN dbo.Employees AS em ON em.Id = m.ManagerId ORDER BY m.Id

Comment: @ПавелОвчинников Это лучше добавить в ответ.

Comment: Вот это то, и в тоже время не то  По-идее должно быть `em.Name AS 'Manager'`. Хотя, ладно, вы впишите в ответ этот вариант, вместо нынешнего, и я поставлю ответу галку. Спасибо.